# Application Rejected from appstore due to this crash log

Tags: ios, xcode

My app got rejected by Apple App Store review team because it was crashed on iPad air running iOS 7.1.1, as soon as the app lunches, as they said.  They've attached a crash report that I have no idea how to investigate and will appreciate if you can help:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3097decb 0x3b557ce7 0x308b7791 0x2040d 0x3135e117 0x30948f0f 0x30948b2b 0x30946eb3 0x308b1729 0x308b150b 0x357ea6d3 0x33212871 0x132f2f 0x3ba55ab7)
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb0c1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bb747b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3babcff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3af0b98b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3af246e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b557f7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3af221b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3af21d13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b557e2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x308b179b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                  0x308b1507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x357ea6cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x3321286d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  SocialCheckin                   0x00132f2b 0x7000 + 1228587
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3ba55ab5 start + 1
```

Comment: I doubt if this is the only information they have provided. Could you share their description as well, and screenshots if any?

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash report and you'll see where in your code the issue is.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Wrong. The exception reason won't be shown, since Apple never shows that. **But** the stack trace would show where in the apps code the exception will be raised, and with the source it should be possible to guess which exception is raised.

Comment: that stack trace doesn't show anything though  0x700 SocialCheckin = main

Comment: ah sorry didn't see that separate exception stack trace -- my bad

Comment: The line below `Last Exception Backtrace` shows a short version of the stack trace. With symbolication this will be expanded. Each hex value is an address of a stack frame.

Answer (score -1):

attention to the follows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
```

It is not caused by your code. I think the system send some code like kill to your app.

Maybe the following reason:

Your app has not launched in five seconds.

Comment: ? no ... it was an exception I think.

Comment: This is wrong. If the system would kill the app, the app would never get any notice. In addition, if the app would not start within 10 seconds, there would be no stack trace at all in the crash report. The crash is caused by an exception, that's why there is a `Last Exception Backtrace` in the crash report. `SIGABRT` is usually caused by some code **inside** the app calling `abort()`, which is normal whenever an exception occurs.

Comment: I think we can't resymbol by the symbolicate file because the  crash backtrace is not crashed in the app's code .
'
11  GraphicsServices                0x357ea6cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x3321286d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  SocialCheckin                   0x00132f2b 0x7000 + 1228587
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3ba55ab5 start + 1
'
There is only one line in the app's code 
"13  SocialCheckin"   This must be the main(){}
If we can resymbol, they should hava other lines start with SocialCheckin

Comment: The app **did** crash in the apps code. Symbolication is a process if fetching the code at a given address, this is independent of where the crash happens. The line below `Last Exception Backtrace` is a short format for a stack trace and symbolication will expand it and resolve the given addresses in that line. And it will show where in the app the crash happened.

Comment: The stack trace of the main thread is normal for **every** crash that was triggered by raising an exception.

Comment: Correct, the app crashed in the main thread. But when you get an exception, the Cocoa runtime catches it ind re-throws it and the actual crash caused by calling `abort` happens in the next runloop. So  the stack trace of the main thread never shows the situation at the moment when the exception was raised. That is why the crash report shows an additional `Last Exception Backtrace`.

Comment: @Kerni:Please explain what is the reason exactly

Comment: @AnkitPanwar: You have to symbolicate the crash report. Without that nobody can tell you what the reason of the crash is.

Comment: I think it's not crashed in the app's code because all the crash in the app must have the line start with the appname in the Exception backtrace. maybe there are some difference when debug in xcode. I was wrong.

Comment: @AnkitPanwar , you should find the symbol files named xxx.DSYM. and you should use otool to work out the address's meaning

Comment: @kerni: please tell me how to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: @AnkitPanwar: there is lots of documentation available via searching here or another search engine. Read these: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html and http://iostechblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/symbolicating-crash-logs/  and http://confusatory.org/post/62734019749/symbolicating-an-ios-application-crash-report

Comment: @Kerni: I am providing .dsym file please send symbolicate crash please help me

Comment: @AnkitPanwar: You really really should be able to do this yourself and also learn to read a crash report. I highly recommend reading the links. As a one time exception I would offer to help: Post a link to the full crash report and the dSYM in your question and not in a comment!

Comment: @Kerni: Please help me i can't find any solution